# Editing information displayed in page header

Tags: usability, design-patterns, header

I have a page header which looks like this example from [Ant Design](https://ant.design/components/page-header/):

[image]

I need a way to edit the information displayed in the header.

Initially I thought of having an Edit button in the header for that purpose. However, it may lead a user to think that it is for editing the entire page. So should I remove the Edit from the header and duplicate the display of header information under relevant sections/tabs on the page and provide local edits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dedicated `EDIT` button or icon is an option of course. For example, your Ant Design example has such icon next to `Title`.

There are other options too though. One would be changing the mouse cursor when hovering the editable header, title, or essentially any editable field. Upon left click, the text becomes an edit field. So, basically user have to click on the text, label, etc. to start editing it in place. This way the page is clean from any extra elements and user is not forced to navigate somewhere else for editing. Simplicity.